# Throwing exception outside of Flux/Mono reactive pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, mono, project-reactor, spring-jms, flux

In my spring JMS listener onMessage method, I am using a reactive pipeline as as below where I receive a JMS message from a queue and transform that to a different format and publishing to another topic. Without the reactive flow, in the case of failure in output publishing, I can throw a runtimeexception for the same message to redeliver from the queue. But by using the below flow of reactive approach, I cannot find a way to throw an exception outside. Can you please help on what should be the approach here for throwing the exception outside to get the message redelivered

```
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
      Mono.just(message)
     .doOnNext(LoggingUtil::logMessage)
     .flatMapIterable(messageTransformer::transformToTriggerEvents)
     .doOnNext(LoggingUtil::logTriggerEvent)
     .doOnNext(triggerEventPublisher::publish)
     .subscribe();                                                                                    
    }
```

Comment: The usual answer here would just be to raise a `Mono.error()` in the `flatMap()` call that is responsible for the output publishing. That won't work here however because you haven't really got a reactive pipeline at all - you're just using the reactor library to wrap an incoming message and then process it in-place. A reactive approach would actually be *returning* a `Mono<Void>` or similar, letting the framework handle the subscription, and in that case your error would be propagated correctly.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerry Do you think I can throw an exception out of the onMessage method in this case